Civilization 4 - Fall From heaven 2 - how to add entry for Azer to Civilopedia?
In the Civilopedia of Civilization 4 - Fall from heaven 2 there is no entry for the "Azer" Unit. There is however a pretty good knowledge entry on fandom.com that describes the unit's attributes.
Can I somehow add the entry to the Civilopedia manually and fill in the gap?
the mod "Fall from heaven 2" requires Beyond the Sword
here is a screen shot of the units:


Some additional Info that might improve this question and my answer: Is this the base game Civ 4 or are you playing Beyond the Sword? Can you add Screenshots of the Entries of that Unit in the Civilopedia to show directly what is missing?

@TreeSpawned thanks for the feedback - i try to give the requested information and would be glad to give more infow when more is needed - so far i found the unit entries unter Civ4\Beyond the Sword\Mods\Fall from Heaven 2\Assets\XML\Units but no civilopedia entries

Are you sure that unit is even in the game? Your screenshot shows it not even being in the list, this, in my experience, can only mean it's not in the game. You have found the unit entries in your file, is there an Azer unit in there anywhere? If yes, can you add it to your question? Can you even create that unit in the game? Can you go into a world edit and see if it is in the list of avaiable units? Give me a screenshot of that if you can.

The Wiki you linked also states this unit is in the categories "Units without a Unit Class", "Unbuildable Units" and "Event Units". My hunch is, that it not appearing has something to do with being in one of these categories, but I will know for sure, when you link it's XML declaration, if it has one.

@TreeSpawned i think you are right these entries must somehow be explicitly removed from the wiki. I guess you are right that the combination of these three attributes Units without a Unit Class, Unbuildable Units and Event Units prevents the entry at all - i'll take your answer as accepted since you spend so much time on helping me and i am pretty sure that would normally be working!

Okay, glad to help. I added a final paragraph to my answer to record our conclusion/answer, so it's not lost in the comments.

You can do this by editing the XML Files
I am not familiar with this mod, but in general, you can edit Civilopedia entries of units following these steps:

Find the unit's declaration and get the name of its Civilopedia tag. The unit's declaration is usually found in the CIV4UnitInfos.xml file which is in the folder Assets/XML/Units. Within this declaration you will find the Civilopedia Tag and within it the unit's Tag for the Civilopedia. If this is empty you should fill it, preferably using the naming scheme used by the other entries. If this unit declaration does not exist, it means this unit is not in the game at all and therefore doesn't appear in the civilopedia.

As an example, here is the declaration of the Archer:
<UnitInfo>
    <Class>UNITCLASS_ARCHER</Class>
    <Type>UNIT_ARCHER</Type>
    [...]
    <Civilopedia>TXT_KEY_UNIT_ARCHER_PEDIA</Civilopedia>
    [...]
</UnitInfo>


Search for the unit's Civilopedia entry. Using this tag, you can look around if there is an existing Civilopedia entry. It will probably be in the file CIV4GameText_Civilopedia_Units.xml in the folder Assets/XML/Text. Note that this doesn't determine if the unit appears in the Civilopedia, this just controls the description text there for it.

Here is the entry for the Archer:
<TEXT>
    <Tag>TXT_KEY_UNIT_ARCHER_PEDIA</Tag>
    <English>[TAB]The bow and arrow, invented in prehistoric times, greatly improved the hunting skills of early man, allowing him to kill his targets from a distance. [...]</English>
    [...]
</TEXT>

It might be that the Civilopedia entry for your specific unit is not showing because there is a typo or some other minor mistake within one of these steps. However if you cannot find any Civilopedia entry at all the unit's XML declaration is either missing completely, or the creators of this mod specifically declared this unit in a way, that disables it from being shown in the Civilopedia.
Make sure you edit these values at the right place
The above is an example of editing the base values of archer. In order to edit these for a mod, you would first have to find the mod's folder. It's typically under your game's base folder and then mods. If you play one of the expansions pack, you need to first go into the Beyond the Sword or Warlords subfolders and then in the mods folder's inside of those.
Note that not all mods have all of the files and folders of the base game in them. They typically only have the ones they are actually changing and the game knows that it must use its regular assets for the files that are missing in the mod. I would assume your mod should have its own copies of both files mentioned. If not just copy those  files from the game's base Assets folder into the mod folder using the same folder structure and then edit them there.
In your case the developers probably disabled that unit's entry
If the Azer is a unit in the mod, but not shown in the Civilopedia, that is an odd case, that I haven't encountered before. My guess would be, that it has something to do with the categories, that this unit is classed into in the wiki: "Units without a Unit Class", "Unbuildable Units" and "Event Units". One of these probably makes it so, the unit is not appearing in the Civilopedia.
To know for certain we would have to take a look at its XML declaration and compare it with a unit from the base game or another unit in the mod, that appears in the civilopedia and see if there are any important differences or missing values.

hehe - make sure you edit these values at the right place

yes again, thank you - i think your answer totally hit the point even though it was not working for that special mod! great answer and great support!!! keep that up!
